# Selenium C# System.AggregateException when clicking on a button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting an exception when clicking on a button.

I am not sure why I am getting this error.  Can you help me?

```
public void Save_AccountBalances()
 {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        IWebElement saveButton = Browser.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("class=['primaryButton largeButton']"))[0];
        saveButton.Click();
  }
```

Webdriver 2.53.1.0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDI1I.png)

[Element I am trying to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k80U3.png)

Answer (score 0):

try using the following selector:

```
IWebElement saveButton = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.primaryButton"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using incorrect syntax in `By.CssSelector`. In `CssSelector` the class Attribute denotes using `.` and also using `FindElements` which returns collection of IWebElements as `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` but you are expecting only single `IWebElement` which is wrong, So you should try using `FindElement` instead which returns Single object of `IWebElement` as below :-

```
IWebElement saveButton = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".primaryButton.largeButton"));
 saveButton.Click();
```

Hope it helps...:)